# Toplink JPA Inheritance - Summary/Detail relationship

Tags: java, inheritance, jpa, orm, toplink

I'm using toplink JPA in a webapp and I want to map just one table to a class hierarchy. I want to have one class that represents most of the data, and one class that inherits from that (so it gets all the fields of the superclass, plus a couple of other that hold large amounts of data). I don't want the large amounts of data all the time, don't want to hold them in request objects etc. I only want the large bits when someone has selected one of the summaries. I've setup the classes as follows (simplified as an example).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TRANSCRIPTS")
@MappedSuperclass //also tried without this - same error
public class Summary {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    //rest of class etc.
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TRANSCRIPTS")
public class Detail extends Summary {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "fullText")
    private String fullText;

    //rest of class etc.
}
```

When I try and get data using this hierarchy, I get an error along the lines of

```
Unknown column 'DTYPE'
```

So it's looking for a descriminator column. Which I haven't setup, because it's not that sort of relationship.

Is there a different way I can map this summary/detail relationship in JPA? Or should I give up on the class inheritance and have two separate unrelated classes, one representing summary data and one representing the full data (and redefining the summary fields).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

DTYPE it is discriminator column that Toplink tries to access to choose between your entities,
If you add that column to your table schema, it will start working.

DTYPE is INTEGER typed column in database.

You could specify your own discriminator column using following code snippet:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type",discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
class TestClass {}
```

Here is some documentation for you http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/toplink-jpa-annotations-096251.html#CHDJHIAG

Comment: So I just need this column to be present, it doesn't have to do anything?

Comment: It will help toplink to understand which row in database table belongs to which entity in your classes. It will contain generated value, or value that you will type in @DiscriminatorValue annotation. It called discriminator column.

Comment: But each row will relate to both classes - the classes represent the same data item, just a subset of it. This isn't like table 1 represents general people and table 2 represents teachers and I want one class for people and one class just for teachers. So as far as the database goes, there is nothing to discriminate with. All the rows would have the same value in this column.

Comment: No you need to set @DiscriminatorValue("teacher") class Teacher{} and @DiscriminatorValue("peaople")class People{}